# KbWait won't register key press

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I'm trying to collect keyboard data, but I can't get KbWait to work. In the following code, I'm trying to wait for the participant to respond, check if their response is one of two acceptable answers, and then continue. It should only continue when the participant presses 'j' or 'f'.

> ```
>         response = [];        
>         while isempty(response)&&(GetSecs - FlipTimestamp) < 10
>             [keyIsDown, RTsecs, RTkeyCode, deltaSecs] = KbWait;
>             if keyIsDown
>                 r=find(RTkeyCode);%this should be the code for the key pressed
>                 response=KbName(r);%Figure out what key was pressed
>                 rt=num2str(RTsecs-time);  %subtract off timestamp from when window was flipped
>                 if response == 'f'
>                     match_response= false;
>                 end
>                 if response == 'j'
>                     match_response= true;
>                 end
>             end
>         end
> ```

However, KbWait never returns. When I try to run it from the command line, it doesn't work either. It just hangs up and refuses to return, and I have to interrupt the program.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by replacing KbWait with KbWait(-1). My guess is that for some reason MatLab thinks there is an extra keyboard somewhere, but I'm not sure why it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been nine months since you posted this, so I imagine you've already found some sort of solution. But I was also having this problem, and here's what I discovered:

I went through my entire HID list: devices = PsychHID('Devices')
As I examined each one's 'usageName' property, I found that multiple devices were considered to be 'Keyboard', even though I only have one actual keyboard connected.

I then tried each one's index as an argument for KbWait. When I got to the correct one, KbWait worked.

Comment: Even though I solved it a different way (I just tore apart my office looking for a bluetooth keyboard that I had forgotten about), I'm accepting this as a good, general purpose solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I think your problem is the KbWait function.

you used KbWait like ist KbCheck but the output of those functions is different

```
[secs, keyCode, deltaSecs] = KbWait([deviceNumber][, forWhat=0][, untilTime=inf])

[keyIsDown, secs, keyCode, deltaSecs] = KbCheck([deviceNumber])
```

Try KbCheck its more exact than KbWait, because KbWait checks the keyboard only every 5 ms

Here is a Function I wrote sometimes ago: [working KbCheck](https://github.com/wuschLOR/awesomeStuff/blob/master/getRating.m)